# how to achieve tcp ip connection via usb in the mobile phone...What is the process?

Tags: android, driver, mobile-application, rndis

I want to achieve network connection with my mobile and my controller.The controller and mobile are connected via usb and then they need to establish network connection. How can we do this?

Controller and Desktop(windows) connection is achieved through rndis driver. I want to replicate the same in mobile..The controller doesn't have WiFi or Bluetooth features. Can anyone help me with this question?